# Help to run CoherentPDF executable

Tags: executable

Please help me to run the executable file from the archive which I found at: http://community.coherentpdf.com/ under "Download binaries now for Windows, Mac, or Linux/Download pre-built tools now". When you unzip the archive, there are several folders, my file is at `Linux-Intel-64bit`, called `cpdf`. I tried many different options to run this file, changed it's properties to executable. But it won't go.

Comment: Is the file stored in a partition formated as fat or ntfs???

Comment: change in the directory, run `ldd cpdf` and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/757213/edit) your question and post the output of the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have Ubuntu 64bit installed!

Go to the folder:

```
cd cpdf-binaries-master/Linux-Intel-64bit
```

Now launch the command:

```
./cpdf --help
```

If you want the command to be available everywhere on the system:

```
sudo cp cpdf /usr/local/bin/
```

or what I do

```
cp cpdf ~/bin/
```

Comment: Yes, the solution was pretty simple: I was too newbie to realise that the command ./cpdf (while being at the right folder) performs nothing (though there was no "command not found" message). Thank you!